# OpenCV Makefile Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV. I was trying to run the code in the link below on Ubuntu.

[Particle Tracker](https://bitbucket.org/kschluff/particle_tracker)

I did as they said in the README file but I could not get it work.

I get the errors in the link below when I typed `make` in the console.

[Errors](https://anotepad.com/notes/9qgx8g)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: I have OpenCV installed.

Comment: Those look like symbols from opencv_core.  Do you have OpenCV 2.x installed?

Comment: Yes. I have OpenCV and I could run an example code on OpenCV's web site. However, I could not run this.

Comment: I can't get pkg-config to work, but I replaced LIBS with `-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui` and the build line to `$(SRCS) $(LIBS)`, and it built.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be sure to paste your code and errors into the question, not as links.  If the links go bad, then this question becomes useless to anyone who has this problem in the future.

Comment: @RobertPrévost Can you post the new makefile you wrote. Because I still get the similar errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here is the makefile that worked on my system.  Remember that you have to configure your build environment to find the shared libraries (e.g., either through ldconfig or LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

```
CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall
LIBS = -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
SRCS = main.cpp condens.cpp lbp.cpp selector.cpp filter.cpp hist.cpp
HEADERS =  condens.h lbp.h selector.h filter.h state.h hist.h

particle_tracker: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
        g++ $(CFLAGS) -o particle_tracker $(SRCS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY clean:
        rm -f particle_tracker particle_tracker.exe
```